# Burninate the [shared] tag?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [shared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shared) tag summary states that it refers to the VB.NET `Shared` keyword:

> In VB.NET, the Shared keyword is roughly equivalent to the static keyword used by many other languages.

However, the [actual usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shared) is all over the place:

- [Append string to a Flash AS3 shared object: For science](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29567005/4200092)
- [g++ -shared -fPIC helloworld.cpp -o ./hw, core dumped](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29561769/4200092)
- [How to deny access to /etc/passwd on shared hosting environment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29502439/4200092)
- [Cluster don't see shared folder on Windows 2003 cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29501702/4200092)
- [Trouble writing into shared memory buffer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29371398/4200092)

The vast majority of questions with this tag don't relate to VB.NET at all, and should really be using other tags:

- [share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/share) (a "generic" tag for the concept of sharing)
- [shared-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shared-libraries) / [shared-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shared-memory) / [shared-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shared-objects)
- [shared-folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shared-folders) / [network-share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/network-share) (or [network-shares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/network-shares), which *ought* to be a synonym [but isn't](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/network-share/synonyms))

This tag is so mis-used that it seems to be beyond help, so I'd suggest burning it rather than re-tagging loads and loads of questions.

Comment: No, it needs to stay alive to help vb.net programmers ask questions about that important keyword.  No vb.net expert is going to be thrown off by [flash] or [c++] questions, that tag only means one thing when it is paired with [vb.net].  It is a contextual tag, not unlike [exception], [performance], [memory], [debugging], etc.

Comment: @HansPassant I'd agree that it's a useful keyword tag for VB.NET programmers; the problem is that it gets mis-used almost all of the time. Perhaps it could be renamed to [tag:shared-keyword] (similar to [delete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delete-keyword) [yield](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yield-keyword) [as](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/as-keyword) [register](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/register-keyword) [like](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like-keyword) [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/this-keyword)) instead?

Comment: There is no current practice of tagging -keyword onto the keywords of a language.  I fail to see a compelling reason to make a special rule for this one.  Wouldn't work anyway, it will quickly come back.  Again, it is completely unambiguous when used in a [vb.net] question, that problem does not need to be fixed.  If you want to remove it from non-vb.net question then have at-it.

Comment: @HansPassant Would renaming to [shared/static] or [static/shared] be useful, if it is technically feasible?